# Would a Macbook Air (2010) be able to use a 8GB RAM module once one exists?

Tags: mac, memory, macbook-air

I'm considering buying a new Macbook Air (2010) but it seems to only have a single RAM slot (for a PC3-8500 DDR3 SODIMM).

As I require 8GB for my current MBP not to slow to a crawl with some of my usage patterns, I wonder if the Air would be able to use an 8GB module once one is available (which I assume would be soon).

Do you expect some fundamental hardware limitation to prevent the OS from recognizing and/or fully utilizing a future 8GB module?

Comment: What would a puny Air be able to do with 8GB RAM?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The MBA's RAM is soldered onto the mainboard, so you can't upgrade it.

You can't even upgrade it from 2GB to 4GB in case you only got the 2GB model.

Comment: This really doesn't address the problem stated in the question does it?

Comment: @Braden: Why not? His question was is the MBA supports 8 GB Modules or if there is ome fundamental hardware limitation and the answer is a clear "No support for 8 GB, since the RAM is soldered on and can't be upgraded".

Comment: how about unsoldering the 4GB chips and soldering those taken from an 8GB card in their place? ;)

Answer (score 8):

Simple Answer:  No, and here is why:

Macbook Air 11 inch (2010): http://support.apple.com/kb/SP617

Macbook Air 13 inch (2010): http://support.apple.com/kb/SP618

I wish apple was a little more up front about this, but these are the official specs of the new macbook air.  Notice how the RAM says "onboard"  with a 4GB maximum.   This is not upgradable later.  You can only order it brand new configured and built that way.  The RAM is directly installed (onboard, soldered) on the motherboard and not a modular chip inserted into an upgradable RAM slot.

So the answer to your question is no, it will not be able to use any RAM upgrade or size.  If you do decide to buy one, you want to get the maximum RAM configuation possible from apple.  The focus of the macbook air was to create an insanely thin laptop and they designed it around that goal.

Answer (score 2):

According to the picture below from [iFixIt](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook-Air-13-Inch-Mid-2011-Teardown/6130/2), the RAM (in the red box) is soldered onto the board. You cannot upgrade the RAM.

[image: MacBook Air Logic Board]